# ImportError: cannot import name 'odds_ratio' from 'scipy.stats.contingency'

Tags: python, importerror, scipy.stats, contingency

I'm trying to import the `odds_ratio` function from `scipy.stats.contingency`, but when I input the following:
`from scipy.stats.contingency import odds_ratio`

I get the error message:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'odds_ratio' from 'scipy.stats.contingency'`

When I input `import scipy.stats.contingency` and use the `help()` function, I see that  `scipy.stats.contingency` includes all functions described [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.contingency.html) except the one function that I need (`odds_ratio`).

Any idea how to troubleshoot importing `odds_ratio`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to the [changelog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release/1.10.0-notes.html#scipy-stats-improvements), odds_ratio was added in SciPy 1.10.0, released Jan 2023. Are you using a version higher or lower than that?